# How to add class token to Google Speech Recognizer

Tags: python, google-speech-api

```
["$OOV_CLASS_ALPHANUMERIC_SEQUENCE"]
```

I would like to use the above class token to convert the output into CAPITAL LETTERS and DIGITS. Not exactly sure where to put the values if it's not the Google Cloud one or if it's capable.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
class SpeechDetection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        self.microphone = sr.Microphone()
        with self.microphone as source:
            self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1)
    def recognize_speech_from_mic(self):
        """Transcribe speech from recorded from `microphone`.

        Returns a dictionary with three keys:
        "success": a boolean indicating whether or not the API request was
                successful
        "error":   `None` if no error occured, otherwise a string containing
                an error message if the API could not be reached or
                speech was unrecognizable
        "transcription": `None` if speech could not be transcribed,
                otherwise a string containing the transcribed text
        """
        if not isinstance(self.recognizer, sr.Recognizer):
            raise TypeError("`recognizer` must be `Recognizer` instance")

        if not isinstance(self.microphone, sr.Microphone):
            raise TypeError("`microphone` must be `Microphone` instance")
        
        with self.microphone as source:
            audio = self.recognizer.listen(source,phrase_time_limit=3)

        response = {
            "success": True,
            "error": None,
            "transcription": None
        }

        try:
            response["transcription"] = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language= 'en-US')
        except sr.RequestError:
            response["success"] = False
            response["error"] = "API unavailable"
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            response["error"] = "Unable to recognize speech"

        return response
```